# App getting stopped while tried start new activity : AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION

Tags: java, android

## Trying to jump from **MainActivity** to **Activity_sign_in**

trying to jump from main activity to activity sign in. After installing app whenever I am clicking to login button on MainActivity to jump Activity_sign_in_ the app getting stopped immediately. I am using android studio emulator.

### MainActivity.java

```
package com.aj19990321.zomato20;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button login;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Code to Hide Title Bar or Status Bar
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        // Code to Hide Action Bar
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        login = findViewById(R.id.btn_login);

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login has been clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity_sign_in.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

### MainActivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/foodbackground" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#72000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/foodlogomain" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/pacifico"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Zomato"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="60sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_login"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/background_button"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
            android:text="Login"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_register"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/background_button"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
            android:text="Register
"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="skip"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

### Activity_sign_in.java

```
package com.aj19990321.zomato20;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class Activity_sign_in extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);
    }
}
```

### Acivity_sign_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/myBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Activity_sign_in">


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/myBackground">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/myBackground"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
                android:background="@color/myBackground"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"

                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/foodlogo"
                    app:tint="#FF5722" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/baloo"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Zomato"
                    android:textColor="#FF5722"
                    android:textSize="60sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextTextEmailAddress"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/background_edtview"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                    android:hint="Email Address"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                    android:paddingTop="14dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="14dp"
                    android:textColorHint="#494848" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextNumberPassword"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/background_edtview"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                    android:hint="Password"
                    android:inputType="numberPassword"
                    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                    android:paddingTop="14dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="14dp"
                    android:textColorHint="#494848" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button"
                    android:layout_width="220dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/background_button"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                    android:text="Login"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <view

                        android:layout_width="90dp"
                        android:layout_height="2dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="OR"
                        android:textColor="#3A3A3A"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />

                    <view
                        android:layout_width="90dp"
                        android:layout_height="2dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />


                </LinearLayout>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"

                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/google" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView3"

                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"

                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/facebook" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="want to create an account ?"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

### Run : Error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.aj19990321.zomato20, PID: 15536
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.aj19990321.zomato20/com.aj19990321.zomato20.Activity_sign_in}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #105 in com.aj19990321.zomato20:layout/activity_sign_in: Binary XML file line #105 in com.aj19990321.zomato20:layout/activity_sign_in: Error inflating class null
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #105 in com.aj19990321.zomato20:layout/activity_sign_in: Binary XML file line #105 in com.aj19990321.zomato20:layout/activity_sign_in: Error inflating class null
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #105 in com.aj19990321.zomato20:layout/activity_sign_in: Error inflating class null
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1052)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:995)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:699)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
        at com.aj19990321.zomato20.Activity_sign_in.onCreate(Activity_sign_in.java:12)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 15536 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Which android version you set for emulator ?

Comment: I am using Pixel_3a_API_30_x86, Android Version 11, in my project I have used 5.0

Answer (score 1):

Change all references of `<view .. /> to <View ../>`

Example, change

```
 <view
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"/>
```

to

```
  <View
      android:layout_width="90dp"
      android:layout_height="2dp"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:layout_marginEnd="5dp" />
```

Comment: Great, it solved. Can you kindly explain this -- view to View. What is the difference

Comment: When you use a `View` tag you are essentially creating an instance of the `android.View` but when you use the `view` tag, you also need to specify a `class` property to tell the view inflater which instance of class to inflate.  If you don't do this you will have a RuntimeException when the view inflater tries to inflate the layout file.